# Rendered more hooks than during the previous render.(component exception)

Tags: reactjs, react-native

My code is(shortForm)

```
import..
export default function App({ navigation }) {
   function HomeScreen({ navigation }) {
   ...
   }
   const [ItemURL, setItemURl] = useState('URL')
   return (
        <ItemContext.Provider value={ItemURL}>
            ...
        </ItemContext.Provider>
    )
}
```

I am trying to add context API in my app. I am getting this error when trying to add useState.

Full code

```
export default function App({ navigation }) {
    function HomeScreen({ navigation }) {
        const [WantLogIn, setWantLogIn] = useState(false)
        const [OpenAnimation, setOpenAnimation] = useState(0)

        useEffect(() => {
            ...
        }, [OpenSetting])

        useEffect(() => {
            ...
        }, [ItemOpen])

        useEffect(() => {
            ...
        }, [OpenAnimation])
        return (
            <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
                ...
            </View>
        )
    }    
    
    const [loaded1] = useFonts({
        Poppins_Bold: require('./assets/fonts/Poppins-Bold.ttf'),
    })
    if (!loaded) {
        return null
    } else {
        setCustomText(customTextProps)
    }
    if (!loaded1) {
        return null
    }
    const [ItemURL, setItemURl] = useState('URL')

    return (
        <ItemContext.Provider value={ItemURL}>
            <ApplicationProvider {...eva} theme={{ ...eva.light, ...theme }}>
                <NavigationContainer>
                    <Stack.Navigator headerMode='none' mode='model' screenOptions={{}}>
                        
                    </Stack.Navigator>
                </NavigationContainer>
            </ApplicationProvider>
        </ItemContext.Provider>
    )
}
```

This is my full code and removed some unnecessary things.I used react navigation in this app(is that making any problems).

When I put const `ItemURL` on the top of the other const of app function it starts working.

Comment: Can you share your whole code? Homescreen for example

Comment: ok, let me edit.

Comment: I added my full code.(not able to add full code so removed some unnecessary things)

Comment: your HomeScreen is inside your App. Extract it and put it outside.

Comment: Yes, I did. but no luck

Comment: I think there is something with usefont

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using the `useState('URL')` after checking for `loaded`. If not loaded, the function returns null and nothing is rendered, but also, the last useState is never reached.

Now if the fonts are loaded, the return state is not called and the useState is called. Now you have a different number of hooks calls, which is forbidden.

Move the useState above the early return of (!loaded).

```
export default function App({ navigation }) {
    function HomeScreen({ navigation }) {
        const [WantLogIn, setWantLogIn] = useState(false)
        const [OpenAnimation, setOpenAnimation] = useState(0)

        useEffect(() => {
            ...
        }, [OpenSetting])

        useEffect(() => {
            ...
        }, [ItemOpen])

        useEffect(() => {
            ...
        }, [OpenAnimation])
        return (
            <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
                ...
            </View>
        )
    }    
    
    const [loaded1] = useFonts({
        Poppins_Bold: require('./assets/fonts/Poppins-Bold.ttf'),
    })

    const [ItemURL, setItemURl] = useState('URL') // MOVE THIS UP

    if (!loaded) {
        return null
    } else {
        setCustomText(customTextProps)
    }
    if (!loaded1) {
        return null
    }

    return (
        <ItemContext.Provider value={ItemURL}>
            <ApplicationProvider {...eva} theme={{ ...eva.light, ...theme }}>
                <NavigationContainer>
                    <Stack.Navigator headerMode='none' mode='model' screenOptions={{}}>
                        
                    </Stack.Navigator>
                </NavigationContainer>
            </ApplicationProvider>
        </ItemContext.Provider>
    )
}
```